# IE7/IE8 Javascript error on jQuery .remove()

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, list, html-lists

Everything working in Firefox/Chrome/etc. but in IE7 & IE8 I'm getting an error on the jQuery .remove() (v=1.5.2) function.  The IE error is:

```
Object does not support this property or method.
```

The list element gets generated via jQuery using the following code:

```
var add_term = $(this).text();
var new_list_element = $('<li><span><input name="med[' + count + ']" class = "new_med_field" value="' +add_term +'" readonly="readonly"></span></li>').hide();
$('div#create_right form ul').append(new_list_element);
```

I'm then trying to remove the same element (on click) using the following:

```
var $tgt ='';
$('#create_right form').click(function(event){
    $tgt = $(event.target);
    //Remove different portions depending on which element is selected
    if ($tgt.is('li') || $tgt.is('span') || tgt.is('input[class="new_med_field"]')) {
        $tgt.closest('li').remove();
        count--;        
    }
});
```

Link to the site: http://refillwizardstage.heroku.com/refill/create

Comment: What version of jQuery is this?

Comment: the items add and remove fine for me in IE8

Comment: Your `if` and `else` branches contain the exact same code.

Comment: Running jQuery 1.5.2 and they do have the same code - made some changes and didn't refactor.  I don't think that would fix the problem tho?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to say it's a bug. There is an unhandled exception in sizzle, it only happens in browsers not supporting querySelectorAll (like IE7 or IE8+ in compatibility mode) .

The attribute-handler for type receives an argument that is not an element-node(in this case it's an DOMDocumentFragment, looks like a copy of the removed node, that doesn't have a method getAttribute).

As long as your function seems to work like expected you may catch this error.

Put this right after the embedded jquery.js-file:

```
<script>
 jQuery.find.selectors.attrHandle.type=function( elem ) {   
       try{return elem.getAttribute( "type" );}catch(e){return'';}
    }
</script>
```

(Of course that's not a really proper way, but I can't tell you why this call with DocumentFragment happens, maybe somebody else will find it out)

Comment: Your suggested code handled the exception in IE, but I'm not quite sure exactly what your code is doing.  Will this code handle all ie exceptions or just this particular one?

Comment: It will only catch the case when sizzle's attrHandle:type-function will receive an argument that is not an element-node.

Comment: It looks like the error will be caused by rails.js , line 181 by the selector `form button:not([type])` . Unfortunately I can't tell you more, I'm not familiar with rails:(

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are using `event.target`. Try using just `$tgt = $(this)` or `var crossBrowserTarget = event.target ? event.target : event.srcElement; $tgt = $(crossBrowserTarget);`

Answer (score 0):

for example:

![enter image description here][1]

with "$('.item').remove();" it dosen't work well,but use "$('#bgright').children().remove();"
It is because IE8 or lt isen't support querySelectorAll well.But it's supported in some speacial situations.

```
enter code here:<section id="bgright">
                      <div class="item"></div>
                      <div class="item"></div>
                </section>
```

Comment: Image path is missing, isn't it?